# Unable to deploy angular-app on Google Run

Tags: angular, npm, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, devops

For deploying the application on Google Run. I have create Dockerfile with the following content :

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:latest AS build
WORKDIR  /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.19.9-alpine
COPY --from=build  /app/dist/aistudio /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The problem which occurs on line `RUN npm run build`. The logs shown on console is :

```
=> ERROR [build 4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                       352.3s 
------
 > [build 4/6] RUN npm install:
#12 350.8 npm notice
#12 350.8 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.7.6 -> 7.8.0
#12 350.8 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.8.0>
#12 350.8 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.8.0` to update!
#12 350.8 npm notice
#12 350.8 npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
#12 350.9 npm ERR! network aborted
#12 350.9 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
#12 350.9 npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
#12 350.9 npm ERR! network
#12 350.9 npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
#12 350.9 npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
#12 351.3
#12 351.3 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#12 351.3 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-04T08_36_13_047Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 1
```

Any help would be appreciated. So that I can successfully build Angular docker image and later will deploy it on Google Run. Thanks

**Edited**

When I have simple Dockerfile as given below, then the docker image build and run successfully.

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY /dist/aistudio /usr/share/nginx/html
```

In above case the first two screen has been loaded correctly but further from screen3 I have exception like
[image]

Comment: How (and where) are you building your container image?

Comment: On my local machine using Docker desktop

Comment: Do you have proxy, VPN, (or other soft/network config) that can block the outgoing traffic? Can you try to perform a `RUN apt update` to see if you have the same connectivity issue? Can you try to use Cloud Run for that build? `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<project-id>/mycontainername`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you for the response. I think the problem is with the docker image that I have created. It not issue with the deploying it on google run for now.

Comment: And no VPN or anything else which block the traffic.

Comment: @Zeb Could you put as an answer to the post the solution/workaround you found to your issue? It would be helpful for other members of the community who are facing similar problems.